# path from theme css

Tags: theming, uri

I'm trying to include my own font to my drupal website. I've got a custom.css file in my theme inside 'sites/all/themes/mytheme/css' folder. My fonts are in my  'sites/all/themes/mytheme/fonts' folder. The css is called from the template.php in my theme folder.
This is my css code right now:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'slashbadass_black';
    src: url('../fonts/Myfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/Myfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/Myfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../fonts/Myfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/Myfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/Myfont.svg#slashbadass_black') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

So is this path OK? For what I've seen the font-family is not available right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your css in `mytheme.info`:

`stylesheets[all][] = css/style.css`

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Oswald";
  src: url(../fonts/oswald.eot?#iefix) format("embedded-opentype"),
     url(../fonts/oswald.woff) format("woff"),
     url(../fonts/oswald.ttf) format("truetype"), 
     url(../fonts/oswald.svg) format("svg")
}
```

instead of `template.php`

Comment: I'm adapting an external theme so I try to follow the same structure. If i call the css file from theme.info the path will be fine as it is?

Comment: I have it so in all my Drupal projects so it will work

Comment: It worked as you said but the real problem was not having the fonts on the server.